# Show required fields on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the required attribute on all required fields in my form. As it should, when the form is submitted, it adds a red border around fields that are required but not filled out. Is there a way to show the red borders on all the required fields on page load rather than just the ones that have not been filled out on submit? Thanks for any help.

dr1054

Answer (score 0):

you can put on submit :

```
$("you-form").on("submit",function(){
   $("input[required=required]").each(function(){
        $(this).css("border":"1px solid red");
   })


});
```

Comment: or you can do it in css like input[require=required]{border:1px solid red}

Comment: Thanks Araz. I'm not real familiar with jquery. What would I use for "you-form"? Also, will this cover radio buttons and text areas as well? Thanks.

Comment: Also, Araz...I wanted this to show on load, so would I change "submit" to "load"?

Comment: it is better to use css. see put required="required" in the input or textarea and then in the css write:  input[required=required],textarea[required=required]{border:1px solid red}